# HTTP Authentication request always returns 401

Tags: http, authentication, post, get, request

I want to do a request to a server but always get a 401. What could it be?

If I try it in Postman everything works fine.

```
request({url: 'https://' + username + ':' + password + '@api.fastspring.com/accounts/'}, function (error, response, body) {
    if(response.statusCode == 200){
        console.log('it worked!')
       res.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "text/html" });
       res.write("it worked", 'utf-8');
       res.end();
    } else {
        console.log('error: '+ response.statusCode)
        console.log('error Text: '+ error)
        console.log(body)
        res.writeHead(500, { "Content-Type": "text/html" });
        res.write("Error!", 'utf-8');
        res.end();
    }
});
```

Comment: Receiving a 401 response is the server telling you, “you aren’t authenticated–either not authenticated at all or authenticated incorrectly–but please reauthenticate and try again.” Are you sure that username and password are correct?

Comment: @LinasMickevicius No that is 403.

Comment: Yes username and password are correct. I tried it with basic auth on Postman and everything worked fine.

Comment: @Alireza no unauthorised access is 401, maybe I just didn't choose the right words in the i..e

Answer (score 1):

401 is 'no access'.  So, the authentication is working, your credentials are correct (else you would have had a 403), but the server is denying you access to this resource under these conditions.

The easiest way to find out why this should be is to check the server logs, but this may not be possible.  Here is a list of possible reasons why you may get denied when you have successfully accessed the URL with these credentials from elsewhere.

- You are using a different request type - e.g. POST vs GET.  Maybe only one is permitted.
- You are accessing from a different IP address.  Possibly the server is also restricting access via IP as well as credentials.
- Your URL is subtly different.  Some servers are picky about trailing /, or explicitly adding /index.html or similar.
- The server requires https in this situation but you are using http
- The server requires a Host header which is added by one client but not by another.  This can happen on a server with multiple vhosts, or some Java apps
- Some other access rule you are not aware of

Your best way to find out for certain is to check the server logs.